не понятна причина segfault
class Item {
    public:
    
    
    string Name = "null";
    int Price = 0;
    
    
    Item(string aName, int aPrice) {
        Name = aName;
        Price = aPrice;
    }
};

class Map {
    public:
    Item List[10];
};
int main() {
    Map* HashTable;
    cout << HashTable->List[0].Name; 
    return 0;
}

очень долго пытаюсь решить эту проблему. Ничего не понимаю.

main.cpp:25:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘Item::Item()’ 25 | Map() { | –


Вы не аллокировали HashTable.

На что указывает HashTable? Почему выбрали Map* HashTable; вместо Map HashTable;?

я не знаю, просто пробовал разные способы

сейчас попробую аллокировать

не совсем понял, что значит аллокировать и как это сделать

Map* HashTable = new Map;

Эта ошибка вылазит из-за того, что у класса Map есть поле или вектор полей с каким либо классом(в данном случае Item), у этого класса нет конструктора по умолчанию и в вызове конструктора класса, который содержит поле данного класса в конструкторе не вызывается конструктор этого класса будет ошибка.
Вы должны добавить в Map следующий конструктор:
Map(Item List[10]) : List(List) {}


main.cpp:25:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘Item::Item()’
25 |     Map() {
|

Эта ошибка вылазит из-за того, что у класса Map есть поле или вектор полей с каким либо классом(в данном случае Item), у этого класса нет конструктора по умолчанию и в вызове конструктора класса, который содержит поле данного класса в конструкторе не вызывается конструктор этого класса будет ошибка.

Спасибо. Ошибки ушли, но я не понял, что означает этот ответ.

@deado, я показал, как правильно присваивать значение указателям, чтоб не было segfault. Или вам надо было то, что я ответил в комментарии? Тогда вам надо переформулировать вопрос. Это можно сделать нажав кнопку править.

Не понятно, что такое указатели и для чего они нужны. И не понятно, что такое "конструктор по умолчанию". Вопрос сейчас изменю.

ещё можно было сделать Map* HashMap = new Map

@deado, Можно было бы,  можно ещё Map* HashMap = static_cast<Map*>malloc(size of(Map))

Извините, если чем обидел. Просто там человек в комментарии это написал, вот я и продублировал.

@deado, нет, я не обижен. Есть довольно много способов решить эту задачу. В программирование не существует задач, у решения, которых будет только один способ. Вы как новичок, наверное не знаете, это. Тот способ, который я показал в том комментарии, это способ в стиле Си. Тот способ, который описал evo, в своём комментарии в стиле С++. Тот, который показал я подойдёт для любого языка с указателями.

Минус за то что говорите что можно использовать malloc для класса с++. Конструктор не будет вызван.

а есть какая-то возможность все эти стили... выучить?

я учу на сайте roadmap.sh. Сегодня как раз поинтеры и референсы прошёл. Но там про синтаксис вообще пусто. поэтому мне тяжело с пониманием некоторых вещей. про это я ещё один вопрос тут задал.

Да и помимо конструра, вызывать функции нельзя, особенно если там есть виртуальные.

Объяснение, исходя из ошибки, у вас нет конструктора без параметров, для инициализации массива классов, нужен конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров), которого у вас нет, либо необходимо создавать объекты используя конструктор который у вас есть:
class Item {
    public:
    
    
    string Name = "null";
    int Price = 0;
    
    Item() { } // initializing with default values as null and 0
    

    Item(string aName, int aPrice) {
        Name = aName;
        Price = aPrice;
    }
};

Помимо всего, у вас не выделена память под объект HashTable:
Map *HashTable = new Map;


Вы несколько раз написали одну и ту же функцию Item(), это ведь называется полиморфизм, да?

Это называется перегрузка.
